# Gitlab 16.10: The scheduler failed to assign job to the runner, please try again or contact system administrator

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed self-managed gitlab 16.10 and gitlab-runner 16.10 when I try to run a simple pipeline it gives me the error.

> The scheduler failed to assign job to the runner, please try again or contact system administrator.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is as follows,

```yaml
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"

test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```

I expect the pipeline to be successfully executed.